# CMake includes header files with a higher c++ standard

Tags: c++, cmake, standards

My main project is building with c++11. It includes a library that requires c++17.

**CMakeList** (of my main project)

```
...
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_subdirectory(mylib)
add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp mylib)
...
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mylib/mylib.h"
...
```

**CMakeList** (of mylib)

```
...
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_library(mylib mylib.h mylib.cpp)
...
```

**mylib.h**

```
...
std::optional<T> variable; // which requires c++ 17
...
```

When compiling my project with Clang and CMake 3.26, I got the following error.

```
No template named 'optional' in namespace 'std'
```

It seems that c++11 was used instead of c++17. Is there any possible solution for that, as I can't change the standard of my project to c++17?

Comment: Does your program include mylib.h anywhere?

Comment: Only in main.cpp @RetiredNinja

Comment: Then your program requires C++17 if you wish to use that library.

Comment: The solution here is to wrap `mylib` in a custom library that does not expose any C++17 facilities on its interface. That wrapper library itself would need to be compiled with C++17, but all clients of that library can be pure C++11 applications. You will need to take care that all types are properly hidden away by the wrapper; compiler firewall and Pimpl-idiom are the keywords here.

Comment: why can't your project's target compile with C++17 features?

Comment: Thanks @ComicSansMS. I'll have a look at the compiler firewall and Pimpl-idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mandating C++11 standard with `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`, set a minimum required standard for your target using [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html) like this:

```
target_compile_features(myapp PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
```

This will tell CMake that `myapp` requires *at least* C++11 but anything newer is also okay.

You will also need to have a compiler installed that supports C++17 to build `mylib`. In this case, CMake will pick the right language standard.

You may also want to take a look at [Introduction to Modern CMake, chapter on compile features](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/features/cpp11.html).